# Confused about processing power and run time

Tags: performance

I have been doing scientific computing on C, Python and Matlab. When I run a piece of code on a desktop PC, it might take hours to complete. However, during this time, less than 100% of CPU and less than 100% of memory is used.

Where is the bottleneck then? Naive question: Why can't the PC throw more processing power at the algorithm to make it run faster?

**Edit**

In particular, I am currently running a vectorized loop (that does not do any I/O) in Matlab that has been going on for 2 hours and task manager says 40-38% CPU usage (and 28% memory) all these time. Why doesn't the PC use 90% CPU instead and does this faster?

Comment: Look up "multi-threading", "parallel computing", "multi-core computing", "parallelization", etc...

Comment: do you have  a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Comment: If your calculations are waiting for data to load from disk, then there's nothing to calculate. That's a simplistic answer, but there are several layers where bottlenecks can occur. There are a lot of variables that can affect it. It can depend on the operations your performing, IO can hold things up. If your system is tight on RAM, then you could be spending a lot of time dealing with hard page faults, which will slow things down.

Comment: @Pete - In particular, I am currently running a vectorized loop (that does not do any I/O) in Matlab that has been going on for 2 hours and task manager says 40-38% CPU usage (and 28% memory) all these time.

Comment: Do you know for sure that the loop is vectorized, or do you just hope that it's vectorized? There are any number of types of dependencies between loop iterations that could completely destroy the ability of any automatic vectorization attempts, and even thwart naive manual attempts. Vectorization and other forms of parallel processing can be quite tricky to get "right"...

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing any I/O? Are you running any other processes?
At any instant, the computer is either running your program (100%) or something else (0%), so what you see is a time-average.
If you do any I/O, your program has to wait while it happens, and that comes off of the 100%.

As far as memory, your program uses what it uses, which may or may not be all the RAM available.

BTW, just because it's using 100% of the CPU doesn't mean it's being fast. Your Python and Matlab code is likely to require 10-100 cycles to do the same thing C does in one cycle, simply because those languages are interpreted and/or do a lot more memory management.

Comment: No I/O. In particular, I am currently running a vectorized loop (that does not do any I/O) in Matlab that has been going on for 2 hours and task manager says 40-38% CPU usage all these time.

Comment: On a two-core machine? That would mean 80-76% of one core. Is your RAM less than your working set? It could be doing a lot of swapping. (That's I/O.) Is nothing else running? When your program is stopped, is the CPU 0% or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the process's priority (or processes if there is more than one used). Depending upon the OS, you can practically cause the entire CPU to be dedicated to your process. Just be sure you understand the implications. I have done this for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Now majority of CPUs feature multiple cores and the program may run faster if executed on multiple threads. However the languages you list do not support multi-threading very easily (while in C you may try with [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) or [MPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/)).

A fast solution may be simply run two or three instances of your program at the same time, if you need to try different input data or algorithm versions, for instance. It seems also you have enough memory for this.